# ValueError while trying to save a pixmap as a png file

Tags: python, gtk, pixmap

How can I save a pixmap as a .png file? 
I do this:

```
    image = gtk.Image()
    image.set_from_pixmap(disp.pixmap, disp.mask)
    pixbf=image.get_pixbuf()
    pixbf.save('path.png')
```

I get this error:

```
    pixbf=image.get_pixbuf()
    ValueError: image should be a GdkPixbuf or empty
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkimage.html#method-gtkimage--get-pixbuf),

> The `get_pixbuf()` method gets the `gtk.gdk.Pixbuf` being displayed by the `gtk.Image`. 
>   The `return` value may be `None` if no image data is set. If the storage type of the image is not either 
>   `gtk.IMAGE_EMPTY` or `gtk.IMAGE_PIXBUF` the ***ValueError exception*** will be raised.

(Emphasis Mine)

As you need a *png* file, You can follow the instructions from [here](http://www.daa.com.au/pipermail/pygtk/2009-July/017318.html)

```
pixbuf = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,has_alpha=False, bits_per_sample=8, width=width, height=height)
pixbuf.get_from_drawable(disp.pixmap, disp.pixmap.get_colormap(), 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height)
pixbuf.save('path.png')
```

This will create a `pixbuf` from your `pixmap` which is `disp.pixmap`. This can be later saved using `pixbuf.save`

Answer (score 4):

In these cases it is useful to read the documentation from Gtk itself, instead of the PyGtk, as they are more complete.

In this case the relevant functions are `gtk_image_set_from_pixmap()` and [`gtk_image_get_pixbuf()`](http://developer.gimp.org/api/2.0/gtk/GtkImage.html#gtk-image-get-pixbuf):

> Gets the GdkPixbuf being displayed by the GtkImage. The storage type of the image must be GTK_IMAGE_EMPTY or GTK_IMAGE_PIXBUF.

The problem is that the `GtkImage` widget can hold both a `GdkPixbuf`, a `GdkPixmap`, a `GdkImage`... but it cannot convert between them, that is, you can only recover what you stored.

You are storing a pixmap and trying to get a pixbuf, and that will not work. Now, what is the solution? That depends on what you are trying to do exactly. Probably it is enough if you convert it to a pixbuf with [gtk.pixbuf.get_from_drawable()](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gdkpixbuf.html#method-gdkpixbuf--get-from-drawable):

```
w,h = disp.pixmap.get_size()
pb = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB, True, 8, w, h)
pb.get_from_drawable(disp.pixmap, disp.pixmap.get_colormap(),
    0, 0, 0, 0, width, height)
pb.save('path.png')
```

Answer (score 3):

While waiting for the answer I actually found the solution

```
pixbuf = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB, False, 8, width, height)
pixbf = pixbuf.get_from_drawable(disp.pixmap, disp.pixmap.get_colormap(), 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height)
pixbf.save('path.png')
```

assuming disp.pixmap is your pixmap object